# Dealing with 3 different dates

Tags: php, laravel, date

Can someone explain me why I've got 3 different dates on my page. So:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s'); // return 2016-10-26 12:34:30
$time = Carbon::now(); // return 2016-10-26 13:10:53

UPDATE table SET update_time =NOW()  // saves in database 2016-10-26 09:36:03
```

So when I echo all of them at the same time on the page I've got

```
2016-10-26 13:38:52 - // $date
2016-10-26 13:10:52 - // $time
2016-10-26 09:38:04 - // from database with NOW()
```

How can I make them equal and why they are different?

Comment: Start with what timezone is your webserver in? what timezone is your database server in? What timezone settings do you have configured?

Comment: Server, database and scripts everything running on same server. Default time zone of Laravel `'timezone' => 'UTC',`

Comment: First obvious fault in your `date()` statement: `m` is months, `i` is minutes

Comment: And your database doesn't care about the timezone configured in Laravel, it doesn't even know Laravel exists - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: fixed `i` for minutes. Okay understand this for database timezone but doesn't `NOW()` tell current time of php not of the database? I'm a bit misunderstanding this

Comment: @MarkBaker time_zone off database is set to `SYSTEM`. Doesn't system = server on which is running?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET update_time =NOW()` is an SQL query that uses MySQL's `NOW()` function, and has nothing to do with PHP (PHP doesn't even have a function called `now()`); it uses the MySQL server time settings

Comment: I get that. But what is mean timezone of database `SYSTEM`. I see this in `System Info -> Global Variables` eg. dates should be equals ( except I'm not sure for Carbon ) but they aren't.

Comment: what is your server OS? ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it is Ubuntu